# ReactJs Changing Class on condition

Tags: css, reactjs, dynamic

I am Learing ReactJs and came up with Rendering Class Dynamically

```
 render() {
  let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";

  classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";

  
return (
  <div>
      
    <span  className={classes}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
    <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Increment</button>
  </div>
);
```

want to know how classes += this.state.count ===0 ? "warning" : "primary" ;
worked

i mean  x += y; should be x = x + y;
why would classes be added with this.state.count

my logic that i applied here is

`this.state.count === 0 ? classes = "badge m-2 badge-warning" : classes = "badge m-2 badge-primary";`

Comment: x += y; and x = x + y both are same, adding x to y and assigning it to x, refer below link, it may help you to further understand operators in Javascript: just x += y is a shorter way; https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) at work

This logic is equivalent to:

```js
if(this.state.count === 0)
    classes += "warning";
    // classes = "badge m-2 badge-warning"
else
    classes += "primary";
    // classes = "badge m-2 badge-primary"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, I think this will make code clean.

```
return (
<div>
     <span  className={`badge m-2 badge-${this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary"}`}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
    <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Increment</button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the StackOverflow, please provide more detail about your code why or how it is working. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could be missing an increment function that sets the state. Looking at this section:

```
classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
```

You’re receiving the state using this.state.count and toggling between “**warning**” and “**primary**” using a ternary operator. In another file, there is likely an event-handler function that will determine what the state is set to when an event fires.

The ternary operator works first and the result of

```
this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
```

Is added to classes.